# Get webpage page content and HTTP status code in C#

Tags: c#

In a C# Windows Forms application I can get the contents of a webpage using:

```
string content = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

And I can get the HTTP header using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
string response = ((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()).StatusCode.ToString();
```

Is there a way to get both the contents and the HTTP status code (if it fails) in one trip to the server instead of twice?

Thanks.

Comment: `request.GetResponse()` is getting you both. You're the one who takes only `StatusCode` from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the data from the Stream inside the `HttpWebResponse` object:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

In this way you will have to detect the encoding by hand, or using a library to detect encoding. You can read the encoding as a string from the `HttpWebResponse` object as well, when one exists, it is inside the `ContentType` property. If the page is Html, then you will have to parse it for a possible encoding change in the top of the document or inside the head.

**Read handling the encoding from ContentType header**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
string content;
HttpStatusCode statusCode;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var contentType = response.ContentType;
    Encoding encoding = null;
    if (contentType != null)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(contentType, @"(?<=charset\=).*");
        if (match.Success)
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(match.ToString());
    }

    encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;

    statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: `GetResponse and GetResponseStream` can throw ***exceptions***

Comment: Why not ***CharacterSet*** ? `var encoding = response.CharacterSet == ""
    ? Encoding.UTF8
    : Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);`

Comment: I don't remember if at the time of this answer `CharacterSet` property was there.

Answer (score 6):

**WebClient**

I assume you use `WebClient` because its easy webrequest-to-string handling. Unfortunately, `WebClient` does not expose the HTTP response code. You can either assume the response was positive (`2xx`) unless you get an [exception and read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574659/how-to-get-status-code-from-webclient):

```
try
{
    string content = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)we.Response;     
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
}
```

Or if you're really interested in the success code you can use reflection as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574659/how-to-get-status-code-from-webclient).

---

**HttpClient**

You can also use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're on .NET 4.5, which does expose the response code, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646052/how-to-determine-a-404-response-status-when-using-the-httpclient-getasync):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;       
}
```

---

**HttpWebRequest**

Alternatively, you can just use `HttpWebRequest` to get the status and response [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543324/how-to-convert-webresponse-getresponsestream-return-into-a-string):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

   string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
   var statusCode = response.StatusCode;    
}
```

Comment: `GetResponse and GetResponseStream` can throw ***exceptions***

Comment: GetResponse and GetResponseStream, --will-- throw exception in case of server error (like 404), and you'll not get the content...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have not realised, that in the second case you have access to the content as well (although it takes a little more effort to get as a string).

Look at the Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx which shows you how to ge a response stream from the web response, and then how to get the string data from that stream.

Answer (score 0):

> And I can get the HTTP header using:
>   request.Method = "GET";

Method **GET** returns HEAD and BODY sections in response.
HTTP also support a method **HEAD** - which returns HEAD section only.

You can get BODY from HttpWebResponse using [GetResponseStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).