# HttpClient, catch can't connect

Tags: c#, httpclient, asynchttpclient

I have the following code:

```
        ProgressMessageHandler progress = new ProgressMessageHandler();
        progress.HttpSendProgress += new EventHandler<HttpProgressEventArgs>(HttpSendProgress);
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        message.Content = content;
        message.RequestUri = new Uri("http://myaddress");
        var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress);
        sending = client.SendAsync(message);


    private void HttpSendProgress(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
    {
         //....
    }
```

I want to catch a situation, when "myaddress" is not available. Method HttpSendProgress is called when progress is active, so, I can't check in this method.
Any way to check if "myaddress" is available. I have an idea to start one more thread to check when HttpSendProgress is called last time. But maybe there is a standard method?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can check if the address is a working address in the progress event. You need to check the status after the response has come back.

```
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
```

[How to determine a 404 response status when using the HttpClient.GetAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646052/how-to-determine-a-404-response-status-when-using-the-httpclient-getasync)

Comment: response is not come back. It waits unlimited time :(

Comment: Have you set `timeout`? `client.Timeout = Timespan.FromSeconds(30)`. This should comeback with a response in 30 seconds