# Is it possible to check if a file at a url exists without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#

I would like to use C# to check if a file exists at a specified url without triggering and catching a 404 error as in the code below.

```
bool urlExists = true;
try {
    using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
        byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(myUrl);                                
    }
}
catch (WebException) {
    urlExists = false;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646052/how-to-determine-a-404-response-status-when-using-the-httpclient-getasync

Comment: I'd recommend using `HttpClient` over `WebClient`